# How to: Report download progress for CloudKit operations

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Article #31 [here](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/topics/36-cloudkit) hints that CKQueryOperation reports download progress.

Looking at the API, I can't see how.  Am I being blind ?

The 'add' function of CKDatabase and the naming conventions used throughout, all smell very much like NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. But it looks all hidden away.

Answer (score 0):

`CKQueryOperation` provides a per record execution block, `recordFetchedBlock`. I believe the author in the article you cite is suggesting you can update progress indicators there, each time you receive a new record.

The problem is, what type of update do you want to provide? If a simple count of received records is enough, this approach is fine. If you're trying to update the percentage on a progress bar, I don't see this working as you don't know the total record count until the final completion block. (unless you know the expected record count beforehand, maybe through cached data)